# Push audio file/stream via android push

Tags: android, push

I need to find a way to press a button on my app and it plays an audio file on a connected phone (connected via phone call).  I would like the message to auto-open and play immediately on connected user's phone.  Any suggestions?

Comment: There's no standard mechanism in Android to signal over a connected phone call, so you'd have to figure out the remote number/party and use some other channel such as SMS or the network - *if* the phone/carrier supports doing that while on a call, which not all do.

Comment: But is it possible to send the audio file via mms that will autoplay?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play one audio file from one phone to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664466/play-one-audio-file-from-one-phone-to-another)

Comment: I see you are trying to improve your reputation status on another question. I wish you luck with that, but you should know that asking questions that are a clear dup of your earlier ones won't help in that endeavour. If you could avoid doing that in the future, that'd be great!

Comment: I really wasn't trying to subvert the system...I was actually trying to do it the right way.  Sorry if it seems that way.  This particular question wasn't even voted on (up or down) so I was only trying to resolve my problem and show everyone that I fixed it on my own and then OFFER my solution for those that might be in similar binds...